# JS Script Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is Not Defined When Loading HTML File to Server

Tags: javascript, html, get, nav, uncaught-reference-error

I'm having some trouble with a small bit of code. Essentially, I inserted a small script into our HTML webpage to pull a navigation/menu bar in from a separate file - so that I can make changes to it sitewide as I please.

Initially, the code would not load locally. I understand this is a common issue with some scripts, so I overlooked it since it worked in my Browser-Plus view within my IDE (Atom).

Now, I had our IT manager upload the test file of our homepage to see if it works live as well. It does not. The page is fine but the menu bar is not appearing as it does in my IDE viewer.

I checked the JS Console, and my function line throws an Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is Not Defined.

Can anyone tell me a workaround or different approach?

My boss is not very tech savvy and will not allow the code to go live until I can show him that it works locally - which is starting to seem like an impossible task. I'm not a developer by trade, I just do our website work because I have some webdev knowledge, so this is not exactly in my wheelhouse.

Code below.

'''

```
    <!--THIS SCRIPT PLACES THE MENU BAR-->
            <script>
                $.get("nav.html", function(data){
                    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
                });
            </script>
    <!--END MENU SCRIPT-->
```

'''

I also tried:

'''

```
    <!--THIS SCRIPT PLACES THE MENU BAR-->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
            });
            </script>
    <!--END MENU SCRIPT-->
```

'''

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can't use JQuery unless you include the script reference to the library and make sure you do that before your script that utilizes it. https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Hey @ScottMarcus, thanks for the speedy reply. I may be doing it wrong, as I said I don't use JS often, but I have tried including the src in the head as well:              
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

Comment: `$` is the signature of JQuery. adding JQuery (before your script) should solve the problem

Comment: According to the path you've shown, you would have the jquery file in the root of your web server directory structure. Is that where you have it? If you look at the Network tab of your browser's development tools, do you see a 404 error being reported?

Comment: Try using this `script` instead: `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-1UhTB3WmKG9JumbgcVh2tOxZhZZrApHCFWj+z8QXjo0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: And, 1.2.6 is quite an old version of JQuery, they're up to 3.5 these days. You may want to consider updating your library.  `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Also (FYI) `language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"` do not need to be added to the `script` element as both are default values. It looks like you've found some very old file to "borrow" your code from.

Comment: I do not see a 404 in the Network tab, no. Everything form my limited knowledge appears good to go. When I tell chrome to allow unsecured content, it shows perfectly similar to my IDE browser view.

Comment: Have you tried swapping in one of the scripts I show above instead of yours?

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I did - it now works live. I uploaded my duplicate of our homepage to the server and everything seems good. Now for the trickier part - it still won't display locally if I click the HTML file in our directory. Not a huge deal, but my boss won't let me go live until I can show it works locally. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "locally". Your doing an AJAX request and AJAX must be executed on a web server via an HTTP/S request. You can't just simply open up the file from the file system and make it work. You can load it up to a "locally" running web server (i.e. `http://localhost`), but it must run on a server.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, that makes sense. Sorry for the questions, like I mentioned I'm not a webdev, just a marketing guy who knows slightly more than the others around me. So my best bet would be to explain to him exactly what you just said? Up to this point he insists that there is no reason code shouldn't be executable or viewable by just clicking the HTML file. I knew that is not the case, but don't know the technical ins and outs well enough to give him a convincing reason as to WHY that is how it works. Thanks again for the hand holding by the way.

Comment: Yes, explain to him that Asynchronous JavaScript and XML (AJAX) is being used with the JQuery `.get()` call and AJAX ***must*** execute against a server, which means making an HTTP/S call and in order to do that you must have a server to call against. You can set up a locally running server, but you must have a server.